# Facebook Open Graph Beta: OAuthException

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth

Trying to test the new Open Graph Beta to post a new action.

I'm following the official [tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/tutorial/#create-object)

It says to publish an action you would use this POST

```
    For example, sending a POST to:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/YOUR_NAMESPACE:cook
       ?recipe=OBJECT_URL&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

But in the JS call. There is no access token

```
FB.api('/me/YOUR_NAMESPACE:cook' + 
                    '?recipe=http://example.com/cookie.html','post',
                     function(response) {
                           ..........
                }
```

I get an error when i try to publish my own action. I have authenticated the `publish_actions` permission with the app

- "OAuthException" - "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be possible you are not posting to the correct object.
As in example 'cook' is action and 'recipe' is object..So the 'OBJECT_URL' must be of type 'recipe' as far as tutorial is concerned.

Since timeline is not launched therefore when you create your own object facebook provides you a sample url of that type which can be used to test the posting of your app.

Comment: I tried the sample url and it worked within the JS call. I'm sure localhost has something to do with it as well as FB can't access that.

Comment: Since FB is continuously making drastic changes that's why many times correct code also do not get executed...never mind! :)